# Неправильные данные при передаче по компорту

Tags: c++, boost, serial, buffer

Совсем недавно начал пользоваться всем любимой библиотекой boost, возникла следующая проблема. Нужно передать пакет по ком порту на другой стороне сформировать ответ в зависимости от того что было получено. Написал искусственный мастер и клиент. Мастер слушает порт как только приходит пакет проверяет црц и формирует ответ, приведу код мастера(устройства):

```
void read_data_on_fsoor(int counter)
{
  io_service io;
  serial_port port(io);
  port.open("COM2");
  port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
  std:: cout << "Number of read pack: "<< counter <<std:: endl;
  unsigned char *c = new unsigned char(13);
  read(port, buffer(c,13));
  uint16_t sizeData = *((uint16_t*)&c[11]);
  unsigned char*buffPack = new unsigned char(13+2+(int)sizeData);
  buffPack = c;
  buffPack += 13;
  read(port, buffer(buffPack,(int)sizeData+2));
  port.close();
  buffPack -= 13;
  printf("\n"); 
  printPack(buffPack);
  std:: cin.get();
  if  (checkCrc(buffPack,(int)sizeData))
   {
     uint8_t comand = getComandAnsver(buffPack);
     printf("%d\n",comand);
     bool ans = ansPack(comand);
     if (!ans)
        printf("%s\n", "Error: send answer!");
     printf("%s\n","Response sent!");
   }
  delete[] c;
  delete[] buffPack;
}
```

код клиента(я запрашиваю какие то данные)

```
void basicF(uint8_t comand)
{
 io_service io;
 serial_port port(io);
 switch(comand)
 {
     case 0x01:
     {
         read_version_firmware_master*pack = make_read_firWare_master(1,0);
         int sizeOfPack = 13 + (int)pack->header.sizeData + 2; 
         port.open("COM1");
         port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
         write(port,buffer(pack,sizeOfPack));
         printPack((unsigned char*)pack);
         port.close();
         getAnsw(comand);
         break;
      }
 }

}
```

На данном этапе пакет отправленный на мастера сформирован верно и црц было успешно проверенно. После этого сформирован пакет в ответ на стороне мастера и при получении пакета на стороне клиента там уже мусор. В чем может быть проблема? Пересчитываю адреса специально для вытаскивания информации о длине пакета.

Comment: `uint16_t sizeData = *((uint16_t*)&c[11]);` - чтение за пределами символа, с - символ, 1 байт, uint16_t - 2 байт. Возможно это не ошибка и вы понимаете что делаете)  `buffPack = c;` - присваивание указателей, утечка памяти, запись за пределами массива, потенциальное УБ

Comment: @goldstar_labs В этом месте не происходит чтения за пределами массива. Размер массива - 13, а тут будут прочитаны элементы 11 и 12. Хотя C-style кастование не есть хорошо.

Comment: тут происходит чтение 2 байт и запись в sizeData. Выделено 13 байт же.

Comment: @VTT да, я неправильно сказал, но это потенциально опасный каст)

Comment: @goldstar_labs в чем опасность ? С-стайл каст конечно опасный способ приведения но все же тут просто 2 байта будет взято. Там происходит разыменование указателя всего лишь.

Comment: Ну формально у вас тут нарушение strict aliasing: разыменование указателя на `uint16_t` полученного конвертацией указателя на `unsigned char` является неопреденным поведением.

Comment: Но при первой передачи пакета и того же алгоритма приведения все отлично работает. Проблема появляется на отправки второго пакета, это может быть как то связанно с очисткой буфера (boost::buffer) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в присваивании указателя на первый буфер: `buffPack = c;`. Причем указатель на только что выделенный буфер теряется, память утекает, а при чтении вы получаете переполнение буфера и неопределенное поведение. Вместо этого явно должно было бы быть копирование данных. Используйте лучше `vector`:

```
::std::vector<::std::uint8_t> buffer{};
buffer.resize(13);
…
buffer.resize(13 + 2 + sizeData);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял ваше негодование так как я выделил память пере присвоил указатель и сдвинулся на 13 это же логично в данном случае. Не настолько же глупый компилятор. В вашем случае будет оптимизированей однозначно но не интуитивно понятней, код будет не читабельным.

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев Ага, вы выделили кусок памяти размером `13 + 2 + sizeData`, но после присвоения `buffPack = c;` указатель `buffPack` стал указывать на ранее выделенный кусок памяти размером 13 байт.

Comment: это логично. После сдвига начала на 13 будет указываться на то место памяти которую я выделил 13+2+sizedata. Данные будут находится не рядом но все же компилятор не может понять куда указывает элемент? Этого я не понимаю

Comment: Кажется понял , наверное я и вправду теряю указатель.Тогда не понимаю как это работает в первый раз.

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев Так проблема в том что `byffPack` больше не указывает на блок памяти размером `13+2+sizedata`. Указатель  на блок памяти размером `13+2+sizedata` потерян. А после сдвига начала на 13 он будет указывать за пределы выделенной области памяти. У вас тут неопределенное поведение, соответственно гадать, почему прокатывает в первый раз, смысла нет.

Comment: Вы дважды выделяете память,  `unsigned char *c = new unsigned char(13);` `unsigned char*buffPack = new unsigned char(13+2+(int)sizeData);` после этого присваивания `buffPack = c;` buffPack будет указывать на область памяти, выделенную первым new, в то время как вторая область памяти потеряется и станет утечкой